# Helm template not able to read ip address - can't evaluate field ipAddress in type string

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to create a helm template for Istio's ServiceEntry which has a list of  addresses for static ip addresses. In values.yaml, I have

```
- name: test-se
  namespace: test-se-ns
  egressUrls: 
  - mydbhost.com
  port: 32306
  protocol: TCP
  ipAddress: 10.2.2.2
```

In the .tpl file I am trying to add the value of ipAddress to a list

```
  {{- with .ipAddress }}
  addresses: 
  - {{ .ipAddress | quote }}
  {{- end }}
```

Always fails with exception

templates/_service_entry.tpl:18:13: executing "common.serviceentry.tpl" at <.ipAddress>: can't evaluate field ipAddress in type string

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `with` you make the thing that you have used as `with` the context inside that block.

So, use the dot to refer to it.

```yaml
{{- with .ipAddress }}
addresses: 
  - {{ . | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

From the [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template):

```
{{with pipeline}} T1 {{end}}
    If the value of the pipeline is empty, no output is generated;
    otherwise, dot is set to the value of the pipeline and T1 is
    executed.
```

---

In this case, an `if` seems also fitting, since you do not much with the new context.

```yaml
{{- if .ipAddress }}
addresses: 
  - {{ .ipAddress | quote }}
{{- end }}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use `with` in Helm, you change the scope of the `.`, so Helm looks for an object and not a string, you can read more about it in the [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#modifying-scope-using-with).

but anyway, I think that in your case, you need to use `range` instead of `with`, you can see an example [here](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures/#modifying-scope-using-with)